# copy last row with data to next row down

Tags: vba, copy

I want to copy the last row that that has formulas from a worksheet to the next row down and then value out the row that I just copied down.  For example I have formulas in columns A through W and my current last row is 10 and I want to copy row 10 to row 11 and then value out row 10.  Trying to get vba code to automate process.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your own code first, and show us where it's throwing an error?

Comment: What have you tried?  Questions asking for code which don't include any existing attempts tend to get closed pretty quickly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started in the right direction:

```
Sub appendToEnd()

    Dim myLastCell As Range
    Set myLastCell = LastCell(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:W"))
    Dim lastCellCoords As String: lastCellCoords = "A" & myLastCell.Row & ":W" & myLastCell.Row

    Dim firstEmptyRow As Integer: firstEmptyRow = myLastCell.Row + 1
    Dim firstEmptyCoords As String: firstEmptyCoords = "A" & firstEmptyRow & ":W" & firstEmptyRow

    If Not myLastCell Is Nothing Then
        ' Now Copy the range:
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(lastCellCoords).Copy
        ' And paste to first empty row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        MsgBox ("There is no data in specified range")
    End If

End Sub

Function LastCell(r As Range) As Range

'
' Note "&" denotes a long value; "%" denotes an integer value

    Dim LastRow&, lastCol%

    On Error Resume Next

    With r

  ' Find the last real row

    LastRow& = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

  ' Find the last real column

    lastCol% = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column

    End With

' Finally, initialize a Range object variable for
' the last populated row.

    Set LastCell = r.Cells(LastRow&, lastCol%)


End Function
```

Comment: This worked good.  I had to tweek just slightly as it was pasting values to the last row and kept formula in the previous last row, but your answer was very helpful.  Thank you.